# EXCEL data counting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

I currently have this formula that counts data from cells in `Column B and C`. I need to amend the formula so it won't count if a cell in `column D` is displaying the word `"N/A"`

As you can see in the example sheet, "L03" in the table is being counted as "4" however this needs to be zero as `N/A` is being displayed in column D against code "L03"

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"1",C:C,"L01")
```

The above code is what I have to count everything - I have tried everything and not getting anywhere. Please Help.

[image]

Comment: haaarold, more details/examples on what you've tried would be helpful to those who might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Add the exclusion using `"<>"`

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"1",C:C,"L01",D:D, "<>N/A")
```

[image]

Note this works for your data, as the `N/A` is typed in the cells.  If the `N/A` is the actual error `#N/A` then use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,H$6,C:C,$G7,D:D, "?*")
```

[image]

Comment: For the second formula it's also possible to exclude error value #N/A explicitly by using `=COUNTIFS(B:B,H$6,C:C,$G7,D:D, "<>#N/A")`

Comment: Top man thank you Scott and Barry - however now my formulas are not working at all now. =COUNTIFS(Diversey!A:A,"1",Diversey!H:H,"L09",Diversey!Y:Y, "<>N/A")

Comment: So the question is; is the `N/A` typed in or is it the Error `#N/A`?  As you can see above the formula work for me and the data you provided.  So the issue is with your data or how you showed your data. @haaarold

Comment: @haaarold if it worked, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.